# Where is AnonymousClassLoader?

Tags: java

Starting with some version of JVM appeared two important things to support dynamic programming languages: `invokedynamic` and AnonymousClassLoader. And if to the first it is easy to get access through `org.objectweb.asm` library (necessary auxiliary classes like CallSite and MethodHandle are present in the standard Java library), then I can not find AnonymousClassLoader (sun.dyn.anon.AnonymousClassLoader or java.dyn.anon.AnonymousClassLoader). I use OpenJDK8 and there are no such classes here.

I'm reading this [article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072319/core-java/a-first-taste-of-invokedynamic.html)  and can not repeat the experiments cited there because Java compiler cannot find AnonymousClassLoader. A search in the network shows that there is very little information about this class. However, it seems to be present in the JDK source code [Here is the example](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/invoke/anon/AnonymousClassLoader.java)),

What is the problem? Where can I find this class? Or was this technology only experimental and eventually replaced by something else?

Comment: You should not use things from packages starting with `sun`, they are implementation details that may change between releases, and may not be available in JVMs from different vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class existed in earlier versions of Java 8,  but has since been removed.

Whether it was experimental or not, it was an internal class and internal classes are not intended for use by application code.

- [Why developers should not write programs that call 'sun' packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

---

However, if you are curious, the source code for the class is available in the Mercurial repositories ... and also [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/invoke/anon/AnonymousClassLoader.java) (though the package name is different).